# Jquery slideDown function not working as expected.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to slide a div down when clicking a link
here is how I am trying to do so:

```
<?php
$interactionBox = '<div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:toggle(\'my_div\');">
Send Message</a>
</div><br />';
?>

<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function toggle(x) {
$('#'+x).slideDown(200);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $interactionBox; ?>
<div class="interactContainers" id="my_div" style="background-color: #EAF4FF;"> message
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

problem is, this is not working and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: -1 For "not working". Please take some time to diagnose the problem more and update the question as appropriate: is there a JavaScript error? Is the returned HTML valid/correct? Does it just "work unexpectedly"? (And please, please, if it's a PHP issue, tag it as such, and if it's a JavaScript issue, show only the *resulting* HTML/JavaScript: PHP need not apply.)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use jQuery. Are you including the jQuery file in the head of your document?

Comment: Matt is correct, jQuery is JavaScript library - you need to either download it to the server or put reference to it hosted on external server.

Answer (score 2):

slideDown causes an element to 'grow' from nothing to its intended height. For that to work, the element has to be hidden:

```
<div id="my_div" style="display: none">message</div>
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the div is fully visible, as yours is, the .slideDown() call has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should at least state what error the page is giving. Use Firefox + Firebug for that.

That said, I noticed that you seem to be using jQuery (`.slideDown()` etc.), but you are not including the jQuery library!

Comment: I got it!! dumb mistake, didn't include the library. Thanks for all the responses!!!